# Cannot get boost header to compile

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use the Boost library to split a string, but I am getting a compilation error with Visual Studio.

My code has `#include "boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp";` and  `#include "boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp";` and my project's include directories contains `C:\Data\Libraries\Boost_1.56.0`, which itself contains the root `boost` directory with Boost's header files.

I then have the following:

```
std::string line = "this,is,a,test";
std::vector<std::string> strings;
boost::algorithm::split(strings, line, boost::is_any_of(','));
```

But this gives me all sorts of errors, such as:

```
Error   37  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::mpl::eval_if_c<false,boost::range_const_iterator<char,void>,boost::range_mutable_iterator<char,void>>' C:\Data\Libraries\Boost_1.56.0\boost\range\iterator.hpp 69
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The message is confusing because it's basically template meta-programming having a tantrum, but the problem is that `boost::is_any_of(',')` won't compile because `','` is a single character that cannot be treated as a "range".

You meant to write:

```
boost::algorithm::split(strings, line, boost::is_any_of(","));
//                                                      ^ ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You try using `boost::algorithm::split(strings, line, boost::is_any_of(","));`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4225564/865603) is another explaination of using `split` function.